# Apache configure gives error invalid variable name: `with-ssl'

Tags: apache, ssl

I need Apache2.4 with ssl.

AWS RHEL server I am using already has Apache2.2 and openssl 0.9 installed. I configured my Apache,apr,apr-util and pcre packages at /opt/products/apache2. everything is fine except the option

```
--enable-ssl
```

fails due to a dependency failure (openssl > 0.9.8a). No problem. I downloaded openssl 1.0.2a from open ssl and configured and installed it at /opt/openssl without problem.
Now I need to configure Apache with

```
--enable-ssl --with-ssl=/opt/openssl
```

but the configure command returns the error

> "invalid variable name 'with-ssl'".

`configure -help` shows that with-ssl is an option.

Is this a bug or something? I don't find any reference on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update for anyone looking at this later.
Installing all the pre-requisites before configuring apache solves the problem of apache giving version error. So this command before the apache configuration solved the problem:

```
    yum install gcc libxml2-devel gcc-c++ libicu-devel libxslt-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel libjpeg-devel libpng libpng-devel freetype freetype-devel curl curl-devel t1lib-devel unixODBC-devel openssl-devel openssl
```

and I did not have to install openssl separately.